# Background video not being displayed in React-Laravel App (API)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, background

I am creating an app using React and Laravel. I want to apply a bg video in my app and also have the code ready. The webpack mix is running successfully. All the components are being displayed except for the video.

I have provided the code snippet below.

```
import Video from "../../../videos/HomeVideo.mp4";

<HeroContainer id="home">
        <HeroBg>
            <VideoBg autoPlay loop muted src={Video} type="video/mp4" />
        </HeroBg>
        <HeroContent>
            <HeroP>
                Sign up today and receive a 10% discount on your next
                service.
            </HeroP>
        </HeroContent>
</HeroContainer>
```

**Everything is running fine, just the video is not being displayed**

Answer (score 0):

Please remove muted from your code.

`<VideoBg autoPlay loop src={Video} type="video/mp4" />`

Also, try to use a built-in video tag of react.

```
<video loop autoPlay>
    <source
      src={Video}
    />
    Try to use this snippet to show up your video.
  </video>
```

Comment: Hi M Fizan iqbal, it did not work for me. Isn't muted just for muting the video?